# What is this bean-shaped thing growing on my aloe?

Tags: identification, flowering, aloe, reproduction

I have a miniature aloe and while it's been normal for it to flower once or twice a year, this time something new appeared on the stalk:

[image: Aloe stalk]

B is what grows normally, A is this weird bean-shaped thing that is a new thing. I tried looking it up and found nothing - is this just the next stage of flowering for the plant?

Comment: Good question and clear illustration; We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were pretty close when you described the "thing" as a bean, because like a bean, it's a seedpod - your aloe was pollinated and has set seeds in three pods. You could let the pods dry - when ripe, they should open up a little. At that point, you could carefully pick them and collect the seeds to plant in other pots or cells. If I remember correctly, germinating aloe seeds can be somewhat tricky, so additional research would be needed to determine just how to go about it - and instructions may vary based on the species of aloe that you have. Alternatively, you could just pick the pods and toss them.

Comment: Seed pods only develop on mature aloe plants that are a few years old. Good job keeping yours alive!